# Fixing GRUB2 Vista problem

Tags: grub2, windows-vista

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 and found that the GRUB menu was showing Windows Vista for recovery mode and vice-versa. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem relates to GRUB2 sometimes confusing the partition numbering system, for example, by specifying set root=’(hd0,1)’ for Vista when this OS is actually located on  the second partition (hd0,2) of the disk.  See: http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/installation-of-ubuntu-10-04/

It can be fixed by modifying the GRUB2 menu to point the Windows' entries to the correct disk partitions.  Note that the file grub.cfg has to be edited indirectly.  See: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Custom%20Menu%20Entries